# where is the log file of shell program in Linux？

Tags: linux, shell, logging

Under Linux System, my shell script is always interrupted. I need to look at the log to determine the cause of the problem, but I don’t know where to look at the log?

Comment: If your script writes error messages to a file somewhere, you'd presumably know what the file name is. We don't have a clue without seeing the code

Comment: You can enabling `set -x` after the shebang line to debug your script.